# Connecting an HTML form to a Java program

Tags: java, design, architecture, html, jsp

I would like to create a front-end interface in HTML that interacts with a Java program via an HTML `form`. I would like to be able to publish this project on the Internet.

In other words, the text entered in the `input` fields of the form would be sent to the Java program as arguments once the user clicks "Submit". The Java program would then execute, and send its output back to the HTML front-end.

At a high level, how do I accomplish this task? What technologies, frameworks, etc are required to make this happen, and how would they fit into the project?

Comment: If it makes any difference, I'm using Gradle to manage my Java program's dependencies

Comment: **[Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6961/)**

Comment: @Snowman How do you recommend I go about answering my question then? Beginners in any discipline are bound to ask broad questions like this

Comment: @freezefry Beginners should consult *resources explicitly designed for beginners*, such as tutorials and introductory textbooks. Q&A sites like this are better for more focused problems. Learning everything you need to know to implement a webapp would take hundreds of questions, but probably only half a dozen books; the latter approach just works better for everyone. Which is why even the answers you are getting are just links to tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by checking out [simple Java servlets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html). They provide a relatively straightforward means to implement HTTP methods at the server side. More complex frameworks exist, but they'll sit on top of the standard servlet framework.

e.g. here's a simple servlet method to return a web page upon request

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
  }
```

(from the [tutorial here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm))

Answer (score 1):

One common approach is having a Java container server like [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat). You must program the business logic in [Java Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) or [Java Server Pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Server_Pages). Tomcat can also serve html files.